# Não retorna resultado PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho o seguinte problema, estou a tentar fazer uma tabela onde no local do resultado retorne um valor mas de momento nada aparece. Agradecia imenso a vossa ajuda

```
<tr>
    <th>Objetivo 1</th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="DataInicio" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataInicio" />
            <label for="datainicio"></label>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="DataFim" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataFim" />
            <label for="datafim"></label>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="avInicial1" type="text" class="validate"
                   autocomplete="off" name="AvInicial"
                   onchange="calculaResultado(1)">
             <label for="avinicial"></label>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="meta1" type="text" class="validate" autocomplete="off"
                   name="Meta" onchange="calculaResultado(1)">
            <label for="meta"></label>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="AvIntercalar" type="text" class="validate"
                   autocomplete="off" name="AvIntercalar">
            <label for="avintercalar"></label>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="avFinal1" type="text" class="validate"
                   autocomplete="off" name="Avfinal" onchange="calculaResultado(1)">
            <label for="avfinal"></label>       
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input disabled id="resultado1"/>
        </div>
    </th>
</tr>

<script>

(function calculaResultado(x){

    console.log(x);
    a = document.getElementById('avInicial' + x).value;
    b = document.getElementById('meta' + x).value;
    c = document.getElementById('avFinal' + x).value;

    const resultado = ((c*100)/b);

      if(b === c){
        return 1; //100%
      } else if (a > c) {
        return 0; // 0%
      } else {
        return resultado;
      }

    document.getElementById('resultado' + x).value =  parseInt(resultado); 
})();
```

Quando meto a correr e insiro os valores nada acontece na coluna do resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Do jeito que está, creio que você está chamando a função de forma incorreta, e está fazendo o `return` do resultado antes da atribuição no campo, ou seja, nunca iria realizar a atribuição no campo *resultado*. Verifique abaixo se é isto que você precisa:

```js
function calculaResultado(x){
    a = document.getElementById('avInicial' + x).value;
    b = document.getElementById('meta' + x).value;
    c = document.getElementById('avFinal' + x).value;
    
    const resultado = ((c*100)/b);    

      if(b === c){
        document.getElementById('resultado' + x).value = 1; 
        return 1; //100%
      } else if (a > c) {
        document.getElementById('resultado' + x).value = 0; 
        return 0; // 0%
      } else {
        document.getElementById('resultado' + x).value = resultado; 
        return resultado;
      }
};
```

```html
<tr>
    <th>Objetivo 1</th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="DataInicio" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataInicio" />
            <label for="datainicio"></label>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="DataFim" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataFim" />
            <label for="datafim"></label>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="avInicial1" type="text" class="validate"
                   autocomplete="off" name="AvInicial"
                   onchange="calculaResultado(1)">
             <label for="avinicial"></label>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="meta1" type="text" class="validate" autocomplete="off"
                   name="Meta" onchange="calculaResultado(1)">
            <label for="meta"></label>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="AvIntercalar" type="text" class="validate"
                   autocomplete="off" name="AvIntercalar">
            <label for="avintercalar"></label>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="avFinal1" type="text" class="validate"
                   autocomplete="off" name="Avfinal" onchange="calculaResultado(1)">
            <label for="avfinal"></label>       
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input disabled id="resultado1"/>
        </div>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fiz algumas alterações:**

- Não invocar a função logo de inicio `(function() {})()` pois não há valores passados ainda.  Portanto invoque a função no onchange

```js
function calculaResultado(x){

   //console.log(x);
   a = document.getElementById('avInicial' + x).value;
   b = document.getElementById('meta' + x).value;
   c = document.getElementById('avFinal' + x).value;

    const resultado = ((c*100)/b);


      if(b === c){
        result = 1; //100%
      } else if (a > c) {
        result = 0; // 0%
      } else {
        result = parseInt(resultado);
      }
      document.getElementById('resultado' + x).value = result;  
};
```

```html
<table><tr>
    <th>Objetivo 1</th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="DataInicio" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataInicio" />
            <label for="datainicio"></label>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="DataFim" type = "date" class = "datepicker" name = "DataFim" />
            <label for="datafim"></label>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="avInicial1" type="text" class="validate"
                   autocomplete="off" name="AvInicial"
                   onchange="calculaResultado(1)">
             <label for="avinicial"></label>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="meta1" type="text" class="validate" autocomplete="off"
                   name="Meta" onchange="calculaResultado(1)">
            <label for="meta"></label>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="AvIntercalar" type="text" class="validate"
                   autocomplete="off" name="AvIntercalar">
            <label for="avintercalar"></label>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="avFinal1" type="text" class="validate"
                   autocomplete="off" name="Avfinal" onchange="calculaResultado(1)">
            <label for="avfinal"></label>       
        </div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input disabled id="resultado1"/>
        </div>
    </th>
</tr></table>
```